# Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo`

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I got this error when run `./gradlew assembleRelease` inside android file.
I tried :-

- Clear cache
- remove node_modules and then run `npm install`
- Downgrade react native version form 0.56 to 0.55

all of these did not work . Please help me

```
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareAndroidArchLifecycleRuntime100Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2610Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72610Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2610Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2610Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2610Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2610Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2610Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42610Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2610Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee190Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore190Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco190Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline190Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase190Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3190Library
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0560Library
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader030Library
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\hasan\TEaPP\node_modules (46ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\hasan\TEaPP\node_modules (45ms)
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.

Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\Users\hasan\TEaPP\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 23.073 secs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone is still looking for a solution, please don't waste time in resolving the package issues which is getting corrected in the next release. You can use the latest RC version (0.57.0-rc.3 as of today) and create the project, all should be working fine in Windows. This issue wasted lot of time for lot of developers.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, I got this problem, when I ran react-native link, but it was for iOS . That day I was trying to bdebug alot for the solution. But it didn't find anything. I just restarted my lp , everything work fine for me. 
It just a way I got this problem, I have tried different mentiod .

Comment: I have to just restart the computer after performing cache clear